# Google Sheets query function returns 0 rows when using ORDER By

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am able to use the `QUERY` function to get rows from another sheet but if I try to use `ORDER BY` I get nothing. Oddly, if I do `ORDER BY` with `DESC` it does work.

My example sheet is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18I-GsBzTLtuxwh8sdqeeLb0kLHMc8Z3EpFcN6s17CSU/edit?usp=sharing.

This is my `QUERY` function that only returns the header row:

```
=query(source!A:C, "SELECT A, B, C ORDER BY C")
```

Both of these below work:

```
=query(source!A:C, "SELECT A, B, C")
=query(source!A:C, "SELECT A, B, C ORDER BY C DESC")
```

The first one returns all rows and the second one returns all rows sorted on column C.

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMRmn.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordering by C is placing your values at the bottom since the blank cells have a value that places them higher up. For example, if I reduce my rows to only 20 you will see your formula does work, it's just that they are at the bottom:

[image]

Try this formula instead: `=QUERY(source!,"SELECT A,B,C WHERE A IS NOT NULL ORDER BY C")`

That filters out blank cells and should order the value how you are expecting it too.

[image]

Comment: I am an absolute idiot. I can't believe it. Thank you so much!